# Paypal JAVA REST API examples for recurring payments

Tags: java, rest, paypal, recurring-billing

Does the Paypal JAVA REST API support recurring payment? like getting payment $20 on the 1st day of every month.

Any examples? I could not find such examples.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

In the REST API, classic recurring payments are know as billing plans and billing agreements.

You can find more information here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/

This would be, roughly, the flow:

- Create a Billing Plan with the subscription/recurring payment properties and activate it.
- Create a Billing Agreement passing the ID of the plan you want to use for that particular customer.
- Redirect buyer to PayPal for approval of the agreement.
- Execute the agreement after buyer has approved it and returned back to your site.

Comment: Thanks.  Does REST API Java SDK support billing plan/agreement? I looked at the Java SDK examples, but I could not find any. If you could provide an example using Java SDK, it would be very helpful.Thanks.

Comment: Yes. So many examples are missing in Java SDK which are available in PHP, C# or NodeJS SDK.

Comment: for creating agreement https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/create-billing-agreement/#create-billing-agreement-paypal